# Show div based on url with jquery

Tags: jquery

for example :

> http;//website.com/wp/
>
> http;//website.com/wp/tag/food
>
> http;//website.com/wp/tag/drink
>
> Show div when the page is http;//website.com/wp/ or http;//website.com/wp/tag/drink
>
> Hide div when the page is
> http;//website.com/wp/tag/food

Not something like containing certain parameter or keyword, I want to show it when the url matches exactly.

I want to handle it with jquery only, not javascript nor php(including wp plugins)

Can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, in other words it is JavaScript. It's not possible to use jQuery without JavaScript.

Comment: Please do some research into how to parse URL's using javascript. This is not hard to find on web and this site. Then start your code based on that research and if you have prblems with real code come back and ask questions then. Question is currently too broad and this isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 1):

You may try like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href; //grab the current window location

    var targetDiv = $("#myTargetDiv"); //change this as per your code

    targetDiv.hide(); //hide the div by defualt

    if(currentURL == "http://website.com/wp/" || currentURL == "http://website.com/wp/tag/drink")
    {
        targetDiv.show(); //show the div if matched the current location
    }   
});
```

Comment: check for typos

Comment: @charlietfl - you are too fast...:). Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the visibility based on the value of `location.pathname` and use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) method for toggling based on boolean value.

```
$('#div').toggle(location.pathname == '/wp/' || location.pathname == '/wp/tag/drink');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` to get the value of the URL. Then you can use `.show()` to make an element visible along with `.hide()` to hide an element. For example if the elements id was `foo` you could do something like this for the URL `"http://website.com/wp/"`:

```
if(window.location.href === "http://website.com/wp/")
    $('#foo').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with the Constance of url name.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("multi-step") > -1) {
    $("#navigation").show()
}
```